# Running Scala^Z3 with Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, z3, scala-2.10

I installed Scala^Z3 on my Mac OSX (Mountain Lion, JDK 7, Scala 2.10, Z3 4.3) successfully (following this: http://lara.epfl.ch/w/ScalaZ3). Everything went fine except that I cannot run any example from this website (http://lara.epfl.ch/w/jniz3-scala-examples) without getting this nasty error:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/ClassManifest
>     at .<init>(<console>:8)
>     at .<clinit>(<console>)
>     at .<init>(<console>:7)
>         ...
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.ClassManifest
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>     ... 29 more
> ```

I think this happens because of the incompatibility between the Scala 2.9.x and 2.10.x in handling reflections. As I was able to run the same set of examples under Scala 2.9.x. My question is, is there anyway to go around this and run Scala^Z3 under Scala 2.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not directly answer the question, but might help others trying to build `scalaz3` with `scala 2.10`.

I built `ScalaZ3` with `Scala 2.10.1` and `Z3 4.3.0` on `Windows 7`. I tested it with the `integer constraints` example at http://lara.epfl.ch/w/jniz3-scala-examples and it is working fine.

**Building Z3**

The `Z3 4.3.0` download at codeplex does not include `libZ3.lib` file. So I had to download the source and build it on my machine. The build process is quite simple.

**Building ScalaZ3**

Currently, `build.properties` has sbt version `0.7.4` and scala version `2.9.2`. This builds fine. ( I had to make some minor modifications to the `build.scala` file. Modify `z3LibPath(z3VN).absolutePath` to `z3LibPath(z3VN).absolutePath + "\\libz3.lib"` in the `gcc` task. )

Now if I change scala version to `2.10.1` in `build.properties`, I get `"Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'"` error on launching sbt.  I have no clue why this happens.

I then changed sbt version to `0.12.2` and scala version to `2.10.1`, and started with the fresh source. I have also added `build.sbt` in project root folder containing `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"`. This is required since in sbt `0.12.2`, the file `build.properties` is supposed to be used for specifying the `sbt` version only. More info about sbt version differences at (https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Migrating-from-SBT-0.7.x-to-0.10.x).

I get error `Z3Wrapper.java:27: cannot find symbol LibraryChecksum`. This happens because the file `LibraryChecksum.java` which is supposted to be generated by the build (`project\build\build.scala`) is not generated. Looks like the `package` task does not execute the tasks in (`project\build\build.scala`). The tasks `compute-checksum`, `javah`, and `gcc` are not executed. This may be happening because sbt `0.12.2` expects the `build.scala` file to be directly under the `project` folder.

I then copied the `LibraryChecksum.java` generated from the previous build, the build then goes through. The generated jar file does not contain `scalaz3.dll`.

I then executed `javah` and `gcc` tasks manually. The command for these tasks can be copied from the log of successful build with `scala 2.9.2`(I made appropriate modifications to the commands for scala `2.10.1`). Here also, I had to make some changes. I had to explicitly add full path of `scala-library.jar`   classpath of the `javah` task.

I then added the `lib-bin\scalaz3.dll` to the jar file using `jar uf target\scala-2.10\scalaz3.jar lib-bin/scalaz3.dll`.

Comment: Note that, courtesy of Etienne Kneuss, [ScalaZ3 has now been ported to 2.10](https://github.com/epfl-lara/ScalaZ3).

Comment: @Philippe Thanks. I will share my findings on the windows platform as and when I get time to test this release.

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the project propertie and build file (https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/project/build.properties and https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/blob/master/project/build/scalaZ3.scala) I infer that scalaZ3 is currently provided for scala 2.9.2 only. There is no cross version support at the moment.

You might try to get the code and compile it yourself after having changed the version to scala 2.10.0 in the "build.properties" file.
See this page for instructions on how to compile it: https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3.
If you're lucky, the code will compile as is under scala 2.10. If you're not, there might be some small fixes to do. Cross your fingers.

If you are not in a hurry, you could also bug the Scala^Z3 authors and ask them for scala 2.10 version of the library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am aware that it is only available for Scala 2.9. And I have already compiled it from the source under Scala 2.10 (everything went just fine).

But the problem is with the Reflection API, which is not detected during the compiling time, that is why it gets compiled but not executed. I think something has changed in Scala 2.10 regarding scala.reflect.ClassManifest.

BTW, I have already filed a bug for this.

Comment: I am not sure to properly understand. What do you mean by "the Reflection API, which is not detected during the compiling time"? And if it is "not detected", how can it compile??? The exception you get really point at one single problem: you are running code that was compiled against scala 2.9, but you are running this code using a scala 2.10 library. Are you sure that you changed the scala version before running `sbt package`? If so, can you make sure that you are running your tests using the **new** scalaz3.jar that `sbt package` generated in the "target "folder (rather than the old jar)?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express it well. I mean since this library calls some methods reflectively, the compiler cannot verify the correctness of these reflective calls, so the problem appears during the runtime.

BTW, I did what you said and changed the build script to scala 2.10 and the problem was still there.

Thanks for you answer again!

Comment: It fails at loadClass, so the problem is definitely in the fact that some code that you're using is compiled against Scala 2.9. It is highly unlikely that reflection API has anything to do with it. Maybe Scala^Z3 depends on some library which was compiled with 2.9?

Comment: Yes indeed, I searched the whole library and there is not a single occurence of "invoke", so it definitly does not use any java reflection (and scala reflection didn't exist in 2.9 so that can't be that either). I'm going to build the lib myself and see what happens.

Comment: @Amanj Sherwany: In the meantime, can you try to clean your ivy cache (in other words, delete the ".ivy2" folder in yout home directory) ? If both the scala 2.9 version and the scala 2.10 version of the library have the same name (without the usual "_<scala-version>" postfix) then ivy will serve you the old (scala 2.9) version. Cleaning the cache and rerunning "sbt package" in scalaZ3 should fix the issue.

Comment: I can confirm you that Scala^Z3 does not use reflection (Java or Scala). What it does use, is dynamic loading of native libs (good old Java `System.loadLibrary`). I don't see why this would be a problem with 2.10, though. We haven't used it with 2.10 ourselves yet, and will appreciate any insight you can provide.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I did what you suggested, and nothing has changed. Can you confirm that you were successful to run it under scala 2.10?

Comment: @Philippe In case you are one of the developers/contributors of Scala^Z3, here is a bug that I submitted regarding this issue: https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/issues/23

Answer (score 3):

I'm copying the instructions from my response to your [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/psuter/ScalaZ3/issues/23), as it may help someone in the future.

The current status is that the old sbt project does not seem mix well with Scala 2.10. Here are the instructions for a "manual" compilation of the project, for Linux. This works for me with Z3 4.3 (grabbed from [the Z3 git repo](http://z3.codeplex.com/)) and Scala 2.10. After installing Z3 per the original instructions:

First compile the Java files:

```
$ mkdir bin
$ find src/main -name '*.java' -exec javac -d bin {} +
```

Then compile the C files. For this, you need to generate the JNI headers first, then compile the shared library. The options in the commands below are for Linux. To find our where the JNI headers are, I run `(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.home")).getParent` in a Scala console (and add `/include` to the result).

```
$ javah -classpath bin -d src/c z3.Z3Wrapper
$ gcc -o lib-bin/libscalaz3.so -shared -Wl,-soname,libscalaz3.so \
        -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include \
        -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include/linux \
        -Iz3/4.3/include -Lz3/4.3/lib \
        -g -lc -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--copy-dt-needed -lz3 -fPIC -O2 -fopenmp \
        src/c/*.[ch]
```

Now compile the Scala files:

```
$ find src/main -name '*.scala' -exec scalac -classpath bin -d bin {} +
```

You'll get "feature warnings", which is typical when moving to 2.10, and another warning about a non-exhaustive pattern match.

Now let's make a jar file out of everything...

```
$ cd bin
$ jar cvf scalaz3.jar z3
$ cd ..
$ jar uf bin/scalaz3.jar lib-bin/libscalaz3.so
```

...and now you should have `bin/scalaz3.jar` containing everything you need. Let's try it out:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=z3/4.3/lib
$ scala -cp bin/scalaz3.jar
scala> z3.scala.version
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The separate compilation of java does not work for me. Got build error about references to some classes in `z3.scala` package (which is not yet built). Is there any particular reason you are delaying the scala compilation step? Also, the `LibraryChecksum.java` has to be manually generated.